# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ExpoUpdates' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I am running a react-native app which has been working until we updated some of the pods to install a new library. The error is below when running the app:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'ExpoUpdates' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. 
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

I am now experiencing this error - note we have ejected the app from expo so it is a react-native app. However, with some modules still being used from expo and some supporting unimodules this error is being thrown everytime we compile on iOS.

I have tried the following:

- Reinstalling node modules
- Reinstalling pods
- Deleting lockfiles and re-installing
- Changing xcode version from 12.4, 12.5 and 13

Is there some other issue that I am missing? Note: There have actually not been any changes to the app config.

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ProjectX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "update:pods": "cd ios && pod install --repo-update && cd ..",
    "postinstall": "yarn run update:pods"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.8.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^1.1.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.4.3",
    "@react-native-community/image-editor": "^2.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.4.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^10.8.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.25",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.24",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "compare-versions": "^3.6.0",
    "expo-asset": "^8.1.7",
    "expo-av": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^9.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "^9.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^8.2.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^8.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "^8.3.0",
    "expo-location": "^8.2.1",
    "expo-media-library": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "^5.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "ngeohash": "^0.6.3",
    "npm": "^6.14.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.300.0",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-emoticons": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-performance-monitor": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "^0.0.5",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case I am getting the error on a jest test.

Comment: @Sachin same issue... how did you manage to fix it?